# Create Publishing page from module

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page

I have create page layout and uploaded it to the master page gallery in a module, now I want to create a publishing page from this page layout, I know I should use a module and upload an .aspx page to the pages library. But what's the content of this .aspx page will be? for my page layout I know the exact html and everything, but for my publishing page what should I write inside? should I create an .aspx page with minimal html?

Comment: Take a look at Waldek's excellent post: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/provisioning-publishing-pages-features-declarative-markup/

Comment: @Robert - could you post that as an answer please (but not just the link, obviously)?

Comment: Sure! I have tried to extract the most vital details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provision publishing pages using modules.

Add a new module to your project, and add the module to a feature.

Add a file to the module (in this case named TemplatePage.aspx) with the following content:

```
<%@ Page
Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,
Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=12.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %>
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %>
```

In the `Elements.xml` of the module you can use the following structure:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Pages"
    Url="$Resources:cmscore,List_Pages_UrlName;">
    <File Name="Page1.aspx" Url="Page1.aspx"
      Path="TemplatePage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary"
      IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
      <Property Name="Title" Value="Lipsum"/>
      <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout"
        Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyLayout.aspx,
        /_catalogs/masterpage/MyLayout.aspx"/>
      <Property Name="ContentType" Value="My page CT" />
      <Property Name="ContentTypeId"
        Value="0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F200794..." />
      <Property Name="PublishingPageContent"
        Value="Lorem &lt;strong&gt;ipsum&lt;/strong&gt;
        &lt;em&gt;test add&lt;/em&gt;" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

As you can see you can modify the values for `ContentType`, `ContentTypeId`, `PublishingPageLayout`, `Title` and `PublishingPageContent` to match your project.

Waldek Mastykarz has an excellent and detailed walk-through [here](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/provisioning-publishing-pages-features-declarative-markup/)

Comment: I am trying to provision publishing page using Out Of the Box "**Blank Page layout**" which can be found at **/_catalogs/masterpage/PageFromDocLayout.aspx**. And add Content Editor webpart to that page.
Can you please post how it can be achieve? PS: My end goal is to package SharePoint List and Pages (which includes customization using Content Editor Webpart). So that it can be easily deployed to any other machine.